Cannot programmatically add label to Google Cloud Function
Google Cloud Functions allow setting labels via the Cloud Console. I want to set a label programmatically during deployment for each cloud function to easily track billing for each function.
The resource manager allows setting labels on a project level, but I can't find documentation on how to add labels via the gcloud CLI.
Read the documenation, try setting labels manually via Cloud Console (they will be removed during next deployment)
